# How to detect empty odd elements in Arraylist

Tags: java, jsp, web, arraylist

This is a little bit complicated to elaborate and the title might be misleading but I don't know how to write it short.

I'm trying to display in a .jsp some images distributed 2 by 2. Example:

[image: distribution of images]

To do that, I have a 'while' loop, that for reasons of design, has to go 2 by 2. Like this:
[image: order of images]
To do this I have an ArrayList of  that are my DTOs, where I encapsulate my info (image, title, author).

The problem comes when I have an ArrayList with 3 or 5 elements. If I have only 1 element, it's easy to detect and display only one.

This is my code:

```
ArrayList<Vinilo> coleccionVinilos = (ArrayList<Vinilo>)request.getAttribute("coleccionVinilos");
request.removeAttribute("coleccionVinilos");
if (coleccionVinilos.size() >= 2) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 6 && coleccionVinilos.size() > i) {
        if (coleccionVinilos.size() > i) {
            Vinilo col = coleccionVinilos.get(4);
        } else {
            Vinilo col = coleccionVinilos.get(i);
            Vinilo col2 = coleccionVinilos.get(i + 1);
        }
        i = i + 2;
    }
} else if (coleccionVinilos.size() == 1) {
    Vinilo col = coleccionVinilos.get(0);
} else{
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I fixed this while writing the question so I thought I'd share it anyways.

This is the final working version

```
ArrayList<Vinilo> coleccionVinilos = (ArrayList<Vinilo>)request.getAttribute("coleccionVinilos");
request.removeAttribute("coleccionVinilos");
if (coleccionVinilos.size() >= 2) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 6 && coleccionVinilos.size() > i) {
        if (i < coleccionVinilos.size() && coleccionVinilos.size() < (i + 2)) {
            Vinilo col = coleccionVinilos.get(i);
        } else {
            Vinilo col = coleccionVinilos.get(i);
            Vinilo col2 = coleccionVinilos.get(i+1);
        }
        i = i + 2;
    }
} else if (coleccionVinilos.size() == 1) {
    Vinilo col = coleccionVinilos.get(0);
} else {
    //
}
```